# How can I create a 3D FilledCurve object?

Tags: graphics

`FilledCurve` can create a 2D graphics object; for example:

```
a = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}; b = {{0, -(2/3)}};
Graphics[FilledCurve[{{BezierCurve[2 a], Line[2 b]}, {BezierCurve[a], Line[b]}}]]
```

[image: a FilledCurve in 2D]

How can I put a `Graphics3D` object like this on a plane, say $z=0$, and create something like the following 3D graphic (without mapping it on a polygon as a texture)?

[image: a 3D version?]

Comment: Althrough I cann't see your images, but this post may be useful to you, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14954/filling-between-two-3d-surfaces/14973#14973 .

Comment: Having 3D `FilledCurve`s would be very useful indeed...

Comment: I guess this can now be done neatly with the help of `DiscretizeGraphics`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is some code to convert filled curves to polygons (2D or 3D).

**Updated**

(I had the same idea as J.M., to combine the best of both answers...)

- The code now handles filled curves containing `BSplineCurve`
  primitives as well as `BezierCurve` and `Line`.
- The curve primitives are converted to lines using J.M.'s `ParametricPlot` trick, ensuring good sampling.
- Disconnected polygons such as separate letters are kept as separate polygons. Polygons representing holes are merged with their parent polygon.

The conversion is done using the functions `filledCurveToPolygons` and `filledCurveToPolygons3D`. The rest of the code is helper functions.

The basic process is to convert the `FilledCurve` to a nested list of line and curve primitives, convert the curves to lines, and then convert the lines to polygons. The devil is in the detail of course, in particular handling the coordinate lists to make sure each segment starts and finishes at the same point - this is crucial to get the holes to work properly.

*Examples*

```
a = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}; b = {{0, -(2/3)}};
fc = FilledCurve[{{BezierCurve[2 a], Line[2 b]}, {BezierCurve[a], Line[b]}}];
Graphics3D[filledCurveToPolygons3D[fc]]
```

[image]

```
fc = ImportString[ExportString[
 Style["ABC", FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"]][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]];
Graphics3D[filledCurveToPolygons3D[fc]]
```

[image]

Note that polygons have edges joining the holes with the outsides - these seem to be hidden in `Graphics3D` but are visible in the 2D version:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Yellow, filledCurveToPolygons[fc]}]
```

[image]

To show outlines in 2D it is better to display the polygons without edges, and add the outlines separately using `filledCurveToLines`:

```
Graphics[{Yellow, filledCurveToPolygons[fc], Red, filledCurveToLines[fc]}]
```

[image]

Here's the code:

```
toSegments[fc : FilledCurve[_List, _List]] :=
 First@GeometricFunctions`DecodeFilledCurve[fc]
toSegments[FilledCurve[data : {_List ..}]] := data
toSegments[FilledCurve[data : _List]] := {data}
toSegments[FilledCurve[data_]] := {{data}}

processSegment[seg_List] := Module[{s, pts, st, fi},
  s = seg; pts = s[[All, 1]];
  If[Length[pts] > 1, s[[2 ;;, 1]] = Join[pts[[;; -2, {-1}]], pts[[2 ;;]], 2]];
  st = pts[[1, 1]]; fi = pts[[-1, -1]];
  If[st != fi, AppendTo[s, Line[{fi, st}]]];
  s]

segmentsToLines[segs_] := segs /. {
   BezierCurve[data_, opts___] :> First@Cases[
      ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[data, opts][t], {t, 0, 1}], _Line, -1],
   BSplineCurve[data_, opts___] :> First@Cases[
      ParametricPlot[BSplineFunction[data, opts][t], {t, 0, 1}], _Line, -1]}

coordList[seg_] := Module[{temp},
  temp = seg /. Line -> Sequence;
  temp[[2 ;;]] = temp[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]];
  Join @@ temp]

processHoles[polys_] := With[{ipq = Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ}, 
  polys //. {a___, p : Polygon[x_], q : Polygon[y_], b___} /; 
     ipq[p, y[[2]]] || ipq[q, x[[2]]] :> {a, Polygon[Join[x, y, {First@x}]], b}]

filledCurveToLines[fc_FilledCurve] := 
 segmentsToLines[processSegment /@ toSegments[fc]]

filledCurveToPolygons[fc_FilledCurve] := 
 processHoles[Polygon /@ coordList /@ filledCurveToLines[fc]]

filledCurveToPolygons3D[fc_FilledCurve] :=
 filledCurveToPolygons[fc] /. 
  Polygon[data_] :> Polygon[ArrayPad[data, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]]
```

Comment: I keep forgetting [``GeometricFunctions`DecodeFilledCurve[]``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/570)... rather useful.

Comment: Thanks, that's wonderful! But there seems to be a problem on my computer when I try the example of "ABC". The hole in the letter "A" doesn't show up. And it seems to because the `processHoles` function can only handel the case that polygon x is larger than polygon y, but on my computer y is larger than x somehow. I'm using V9 on mac.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, try changing the RHS of processHoles to  this:  ``polys//.{a___,p:Polygon[x_],q:Polygon[y_],b___}/;Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[p,y[[2]]]||Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[q, x[[2]]]:>{a,Polygon[Join[x,y,{First@x}]],b}``

Comment: @xslittlegrass, thanks for letting me know (and for the accept). I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: On Mathematica 10, the problem of the hole in the letter "A" that doesn't show up reappears. The solution is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57666/5467)

Comment: A sweet piece of code -- however, I've noticed that it does not knock the holes out of the percent character (%).  The triple-donut case, "‰", fares even worse, and comes out as a rectangle frame, with nothing circular in sight.

Answer (score 5):

Cheating a bit:

```
a = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}; b = {{0, -2/3}};

big = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[2 a][t], {t, 0, 1}], Line[l_] :> l, ∞];
small = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[a][t], {t, 0, 1}], Line[l_] :> l, ∞];

Graphics3D[{Directive[Black, EdgeForm[]], Polygon[Map[Append[#, 0] &,
                  (2 b) ~Join~ big ~Join~ (2 b) ~Join~ b ~Join~ Reverse[small] ~Join~ b]]},
           Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: fake filled curve]

---

I decided to extend Simon's fine answer to be able to handle both Béziers and B-splines, as well as enabling adaptive sampling. Here is the result:

```
toSegments[fc_FilledCurve] :=
            First @ If[Length[fc] == 1, Identity, GeometricFunctions`DecodeFilledCurve][fc]

sampleSegment[prims_List, opts___] := 
 If[First[#] != Last[#], Append[#, First[#]], #] &[
    Apply[Join, prims /. {(b : (BSplineCurve | BezierCurve))[data_, rest___] :> 
          Block[{bf, h, t},
                h = Switch[b, BSplineCurve, BSplineFunction, BezierCurve, BezierFunction];
                bf = Apply[h, {data, rest} /.
                           (SplineDegree -> 3) :> (SplineDegree -> Automatic)];
                First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[bf[t], {t, 0, 1}, opts], Line[l_] :> l, ∞]],
             Line -> Sequence}]]

filledCurvetoPolygon[fc_FilledCurve] := With[{s = sampleSegment /@ toSegments[fc]},
       Polygon[ArrayPad[Join @@ (Append[#, s[[1, -1]]] & /@ s), {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]]]
```

Examples:

```
Graphics3D[filledCurvetoPolygon[First @ Cases[
           ImportString[ExportString["AB", "PDF"]], _FilledCurve, ∞]]]
```

[image: some letters]

```
pts = {{0., -0.5}, {0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0., 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5},
       {-0.5, -0.5}, {0., -0.5}};
w = {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1};
k = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};

FilledCurve[{{BSplineCurve[2 pts, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> k, SplineWeights -> w]},
             {BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> k, SplineWeights -> w]}}]
// filledCurvetoPolygon // Graphics3D
```

[image: annulus]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's very helpful. But if we have multiple holes, do you have any ideas to automatic find the points to break the loop, instead of manually break them? For example `ImportString[ExportString[AB, "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]` gives a `FilledCurve` object with multiple holes. Thanks.

Comment: That'd be tougher to do. Choosing where to break seems nontrivial.

Comment: Looks like we both had the same idea :-)

Comment: @Simon, thanks to your refresher on that decoding function. :)

Comment: @J.M. you probably noticed that the `BezierCurve`s returned by the decoding function seem to be missing a point (which is why the `SplineDegree` is too high). I think `FilledCurve` assumes that each line or curve starts from the end of the previous one, so to get "stand alone" curves you need to prepend each one's coordinate list with the last coordinate of the preceding curve.

Comment: @Simon, I had to hack out the replacement of `SplineDegree -> 3` to `Automatic` as a temporary workaround, but that suggestion looks better. I'll try out your suggestion...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the right way is to use `RegionFunction` for this, then it's very straight forward if we have a test function that checks whether a point lies inside given filled curve or not. I use rasterization to perform such test, but i'm sure it can be done better.

```
a = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}; b = {{0, -2/3}};
g = Graphics[
   FilledCurve[{{BezierCurve[2 a], Line[2 b]}, {BezierCurve[a], 
      Line[b]}}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];
i = Rasterize[g, ImageSize -> {256, 256}];

Plot3D[0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> (PixelValue[i, {64 (#1 + 2), 64 (#2 + 2)}] == {0, 
      0, 0} &)]
```

Comment: I upvoted for `RegionFunction`, but then I found your code not performing correctly in my MMA 9.0 (multiple `Throw::nocatch` errors).

Comment: @Silvia I don't have any errors.

Comment: Maybe you two are using different versions, @Silvia.

Comment: this is my approach, since it works for a lot of different kinds of stuff you could make. some functions to keep in mind for this sort of thing: `Rescale`, `Position`.