# Problem with hole filling using filledCurveToPolygons3D in MMA 10

Tags: graphics

I successfully used the `filledCurveToPolygons3D` function to create 
`Graphics3D` text in MMA 9 on a Windows 7 PC; see:

[How can I create a 3D FilledCurve object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24946/how-can-i-create-a-3d-filledcurve-object)

However, when I installed MMA 10 on this very same machine and tried using this technique again, all the holes in the text are filled. I tried using the recommended changes to the RHS of `processHoles` that another user had had with MMA 9 on a Mac, but I still ended up with all the holes filled. The same problem shows up as well with the 2D function `filledCurveToPolygons`.

Comment: I believe this should be a comment below the answer by @SimonWoods linked above. But I can confirm that this is indeed a new issue in MMA 10 (Mac OS X here).

Comment: The `InPolygonQ` function has moved in version 10 to ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ``. With that change it should work properly.

Comment: It does work properly.

Answer (score 4):

> The `InPolygonQ` function has moved in version 10 to `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ ``. With that change it should work properly. –  Simon Woods Aug 19 '14 at 19:35

[Just to give an answer.  Seemed better than closing the question.]

Comment: I am using v10.1 and it does not recognize two items of the code: (1) `GeometricFunctions\`DecodeFilledCurve` and (2) `Graphics\`PolygonUtils\`InPolygonQ`. They stay blue while the rest of the code turns black after evaluation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @NicholasG I believe it's because their contexts ``GeometricFunctions` `` and ``Graphics`PolygonUtils` `` are not in your `$ContextPath`. It's not an error and it doesn't need fixing. If it is too annoying, you could add the contexts to `$ContextPath`.

Comment: A sweet piece of code -- however, I've noticed that it does not knock the holes out of the percent character (%).  The triple-donut case, "‰", fares even worse, and comes out as a rectangle frame, with nothing circular in sight.