# Placing text in 3D (not facing viewer)

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

I am trying to adapt the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121075/text-on-a-plane-without-rasterize), which places text in 3D on the xy plane, so that the text can be placed in any orientation. So, I wrapped it in three `Rotate` statements, first by tilt around the x axis, then by elevation around the y-axis, then by longitude around the z-axis. However, this rotation happens after the text has been placed, away from the center of the axes. Trying to put the Rotation statements inside the meat of the function runs into the problem that I cannot tell from where the x and y coefficients are deriving so as to manipulate them using `Rotate`. Anyway, the original is

```
xyText[str_, scaling_: 1, location_: {0, 0, 0}] := 
 Module[{mesh = 
    DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style[str, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text,
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.2]}, 
  Join[{EdgeForm[]}, 
   MeshPrimitives[mesh, 
     2] /. {x_?NumberQ, 
      y_?NumberQ} :> (scaling {x, y, 0} + location), {Black}, 
   MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[mesh], 
     1] /. {x_?NumberQ, 
      y_?NumberQ} :> (scaling {x, y, 0} + location)]]
```

and my inadequate adaptation is

```
ClearAll[xyText]
xyText[str_, scaling_: 1, location_: {0, 0, 0}, longitude_, 
  elevation_, tilt_] := 
 Module[{mesh = 
    DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style[str, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text,
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.2]}, Rotate[
   Rotate[
    Rotate[
     Join[{EdgeForm[]}, 
      MeshPrimitives[mesh, 
        2] /. {x_?NumberQ, 
         y_?NumberQ} :> (scaling {x, y, 0} + location)
      , {Black}, 
      MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[mesh], 
        1] /. {x_?NumberQ, 
         y_?NumberQ} :> (scaling {x, y, 0} + location)], 
     tilt, {1, 0, 0}], elevation, {0, 1, 0}], longitude, {0, 0, 1}]]
```

The objective is for the yellow and the red "Dodecahedron" texts to intersect each other in this:

```
meshedSol = 
 Graphics3D[{Antialiasing -> True, Yellow, Opacity[.8], 
   PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], 
   xyText["Dodecahedron", 0.2, {1, 1, 1}, 0, 0, 0],
   Red, xyText["Dodecahedron", 0.2, {1, 1, .9}, 0, 0, \[Pi]/2]}, 
  ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 2}]
```

But instead, the red one is rotated after having been placed.

**Update:**

I gathered that x and y come from MeshPrimitives, so I made that 3D and wove in rotation matrices. Till we get a more elegant answer, I moved the result to be an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I wove rotation matrices in the code and increased the resolution and it works, and now with Chip Hurst's improvement not so slow at all. Maybe it will get to be more elegant yet:

```
text3D[str_, location_: {0, 0, 0}, 
  scaling : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : { 1, 1}, 
  longitude : _?NumericQ : 0, 
  elevation : _?NumericQ : 0, 
  tilt : _?NumericQ : 0, 
  opt : OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[{
mesh=DiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style[str, opt, FontFamily -> "Times", 
   FontSize -> 12]], _Text, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.04],
rotmatrx=RotationMatrix[longitude, {0, 0, 1}].
   RotationMatrix[-elevation, {0, 1, 0}].RotationMatrix[tilt, {1, 0, 0}]}, 
Join[{EdgeForm[]}, 
  MeshPrimitives[mesh,2] /. {x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ} :> (
      rotmatrx.(scaling~Join~{1} {x, y, 0}) + location)
(*
   ,{Black},
   MeshPrimitives[BoundaryMesh[mesh],1]/.{x_?NumberQ,y_?NumberQ}\[RuleDelayed]
   (rotmatrx.(scaling~Join~{1} {x,y,0})+location)
REMOVE REM IF NEEDING OUTLINES*)
]]
```

Then:

```
offset = 12; scale = {.5, .5};
Graphics3D[{
  Yellow,
  text3D["width\[LongRightArrow]", {offset, 0, 0}, scale, 
    FontSlant -> Italic],
  Blue,
  text3D["depth\[LongRightArrow]", {0, offset, 0}, scale, \[Pi]/2, 
    FontWeight -> Bold],
  Black,
  text3D["height\[LongRightArrow]", {0, 0, offset}, {.5, .8}, 
    0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2, FontFamily -> "Brush Script Std"],
  Red,
  Sphere[{offset, offset, offset/4}, 3]
}, Boxed -> False]
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: I get about a 10 times speed up by precomputing `M = scaling*RotationMatrix[longitude,{0,0,1}].RotationMatrix[-elevation,{0,1,0}].RotationMatrix[tilt,{1,0,0}]` as a `Module` variable, i.e. this quantity only needs to be computed once. As you have it, it's being computed for every triangle created.

Comment: What a huge difference! Thanks. Adding it.

Comment: Just a stylistic suggestion. In your projected text, you could use `\[Rule]` or `\[LongRightArrow]` instead of `->`.

Comment: The italic Roman turns out not to have `\[Rule]`, LOL, but it does have `\[LongRightArrow]`.

Comment: What remains is for someone to enable left- and right-alignment of the text. As it is, the coordinates for its placement are at the center of the text.

Comment: Why not use `EulerMatrix[{longitude, -elevation, tilt}, {3, 2, 1}]`? And another option is to use the replace on the mesh primitives to transform it to a 3D object quickly (`{x, y} -> {x, y, 0}`), and then just work with `Translate` and `Rotate` (or `GeometricTransformation` with `EulerMatrix`). Alternatively, you can do all of that at once with `TransformedRegion` supplying a function that does both the embedding from 2D into 3D and the transformation. (I'll try to write an answer after working this out.)

Comment: This is *SO* useful.  Thanks.

Comment: This has been so very valuable in my figure preparation... thanks again.... *however* there's a problem.  I prefer to use:  `Text[Style["x",Italic],...]` which works with text3D but the option `BackgroundColor -> Green` does not.  Is there any way that option can be incorporated into your nice code?

Comment: ... also, subscripts don't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry about the subscripts and the background. I do not know why subscripts do not get rendered and I realize that the workaround of placing them with a separate `text3D` statement is cumbersome. For background, however, you can easily place a `Rectangle` behind the `text3D`.