# Dollars with Superscript Cents in text

Tags: formatting

I would like to show the cents of the dollar amount as superscripts inside text.

I can define a function for making the cents into a superscript, but when I add the result in text, the text gets placed in the superscript line.

The formatting functions are:

```
dollarSuperscriptCents[x_?NumericQ] := ToString[Floor[x]]^
 If[x - Floor[x] > 0, ToString@droptrailingperiod[100 (x - Floor[x])],
   ""]
droptrailingperiod[x_] := 
 If[Round[x] == x,(*is the rightmost a period, from some precision?*)
  Round[x](*then use Round to drop the trailing period*)
  , x]
```

But if I then use `Style["I owe $"<>ToString@dollarSuperscriptCents[3.75]<>".", FontFamily -> "Georgia"]` then the result is

I owe $75

3.

I tried to look into `Box` commands but this quickly got too complex. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

**EDIT:** Corrected to handle cent values less than `10`

```
dollarSuperscriptCents[x_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{xv = Round[x, 1/100], cents}, 
  cents = 100*FractionalPart[xv];
  Superscript[ToString[Floor[xv]], If[cents == 0, "", 
   If[cents < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[cents]]]]

Column[Style[StringForm["I owe $``.", dollarSuperscriptCents[#]],
    FontFamily -> "Georgia"] & /@ 
  {2.999, 3, 3.0, 3.05, 3.75, 3.756}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. How does one concatenate `StringForm`s? `StringJoin` does not work!

Comment: Use `Row`, e.g., `Row[Riffle[Style[StringForm["I owe $``.", dollarSuperscriptCents[#]], FontFamily -> "Georgia"] & /@ {2.999, 3, 3.0, 3.75, 3.756}, " "]]`

Comment: I was wondering whether `StringForm` would resolve the inability of `text3D` to render subscripts and other boxed expressions, but I could not make it work. If you could, that would be great. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131798/placing-text-in-3d-not-facing-viewer/131842