# Working with text in 3D graphics

Tags: graphics3d, text

I'd like to add text to the surfaces of a cuboid. I have tried `Text` and `Epilog`, and neither of them worked.

Consider the following code:

```
Graphics3D[
  {{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel @ 0}], Blue, 
    Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 2.4, 1}]},
   {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel @ 0}], Blue, 
    Cuboid[{-4, 3.4, 0}, {4, 3.6, 1}]},
   {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel @ 0}], Blue, 
    Cuboid[{-4, 4.6, 0}, {4, 7, 1}]},
   {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel @ 0}], Blue, Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 7, -1}]},
   {Cyan, Opacity[.95], Cuboid[{-4, 2.4, 0}, {4, 3.4, 1}]},
   {Yellow, Opacity[.95], Cuboid[{-4, 3.6, 0}, {4, 4.6, 1}]}},
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

How can I add text to an arbitrary face of a cuboid, e.g., the yellow cuboid (the color must be adjusted so it is visible)? And more generally, how to add text to an arbitrary point in space?

Comment: You should explore docs. [Text](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)  will do it. Also see FilledCurve and Texture for different approaches.

Comment: This may be useful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128412/9490,  and this, for an example using `Texture`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10437115/4712538

Comment: Also closely related: [“Covering up” text in Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4833/245)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach without using `Texture`:

1. Use M.R.'s `ImportString[ExportString[..., "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]` trick to make your text into a list of `FilledCurves`.
2. Use the function `filledCurveToPolygons3D` [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24976/125) to convert `FilledCurves` to polygons in 3D
3. Use `` NDSolve`FEM`GraphicsPrimitiveToGraphicsComplex `` to convert graphics primitives to `GraphicsComplex`
4. Use the function `rescale` below to `Rescale` the coordinates of the primitives from the previous step to place them in the appropriate positions in the input `Graphics3D`.

Using `text` and `o` from @M.R.'s answer:

```
gc3d = NDSolve`FEM`GraphicsPrimitiveToGraphicsComplex[Cases[text /. 
     f_FilledCurve :> filledCurveToPolygons3D[f], _Polygon, Infinity]];

rescale[ranges_, style___ : FaceForm[Red]] := # /. 
    GraphicsComplex[c_, prims___] :>  GraphicsComplex[
      Transpose[Table[Rescale[Transpose[c][[i]], 
         Through[{Min, Max}@Transpose[c][[i]]], ranges[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}]], 
     {style, prims}] &;

ranges1 = {{-3.6, 3.6}, {2.5, 3.3}, {1.001, 1.001}};
ranges2 = {{-3.6, 3.6}, {3.5, 4.5}, {1.001, 1.001}}
ranges3 = {{3.6, -3.6}, {6.5, 5}, {1.001, 1.001}};
Show[Graphics3D[rescale[ranges1] @ gc3d], 
 Graphics3D[rescale[ranges2, EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Blue]] @ gc3d], 
 Graphics3D[rescale[ranges3, EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Yellow]] @ gc3d], o]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You could always just `Texture` your `Text` in:

```
o = Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 2.4, 1}]}, {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], 
   GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 3.4, 0}, {4, 3.6, 
   1}]}, {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], GrayLevel@0}], Blue, 
 Cuboid[{-4, 4.6, 0}, {4, 7, 1}]}, {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.000001], 
   GrayLevel@0}], Blue, Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 7, -1}]}, {Cyan, 
 Opacity[.95], Cuboid[{-4, 2.4, 0}, {4, 3.4, 1}]}, {Yellow, 
 Opacity[.95], Cuboid[{-4, 3.6, 0}, {4, 4.6, 1}]}}, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 800];

text = First[
   First[ImportString[
     ExportString[
      Style["testing one two three", Italic, FontSize -> 24, 
       FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], "PDF", 
     "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
r = ImagePad[
   Rasterize[Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], Darker@Blue, text}], 
    Background -> None, 
    ImageResolution -> 1000], {{200, 200}, {0, 30}}];
face = {{-4, 2.4`, 1.01`}, {4, 2.4`, 1.01`}, {4, 3.4`, 1.01`}, {-4, 
    3.4`, 1.01`}};
Show[o, Graphics3D[{Texture[r], 
   Polygon[RotateRight[face, 4], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Like M.R. I recommend using texture mapping to put a label on a surface. However, I would write somewhat simpler code to do it.

First rasterize the text.

```
text =
  Rasterize[Style["Text as a texture", "SR"],
    RasterSize -> 500, ImageSize -> 200, Background -> None];
```

Next make a 3D-polygon having the rasterized text mapped onto it. The polygon is is designed to float just above the cuboid surface it labels.

```
label =
  With[
    {rectangle =
       With[{dz = .001}, 
         {{-4, 3.6, 1 + dz}, {4, 3.6, 1 + dz}, {4, 4.6, 1 + dz}, {-4, 4.6, 1 + dz}}],
     textCorners = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}},
    {Texture[text], Polygon[rectangle, VertexTextureCoordinates -> textCorners]}];
```

Finally, add the label to your graphics.

```
Graphics3D[
  {{Blue, EdgeForm[],
     {Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 2.4, 1}], 
      Cuboid[{-4, 3.4, 0}, {4, 3.6, 1}], 
      Cuboid[{-4, 4.6, 0}, {4, 7, 1}], 
      Cuboid[{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 7, -1}]}}, 
   {Cyan, Cuboid[{-4, 2.4, 0}, {4, 3.4, 1}]}, 
   {Yellow, Cuboid[{-4, 3.6, 0}, {4, 4.6, 1}]},
   label},
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: graphics]