# Place two-dimensional Graphics object into three-dimensional Graphics3D object

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, text

I have a labelled two-dimensional `Polygon` that I render with `Graphics`.

```
label = {RGBColor[1., 0.92, 0.61], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, -1}, {0, -1}}]};
label = Graphics[{labels, Inset[Text["Some Label", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}], (1/2) {4, -1}]}];
```

[image: Picture of the 2D labelled graphics]

I want to place this object in a three-dimensional `Graphics3D`, such that the text also gets projected into the plane. So I want an image that looks like the following but with the code modified so that the text is also present

```
labels = {RGBColor[1., 0.92, 0.61], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}]};
object = {Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}]};
Graphics3D[{object, labels}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Picture of 3D graphics with cuboid object and 'label' (but missing text)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
labels = {Texture[Rasterize[
     Text[Framed[Style["Some Label", Yellow, Bold, FontSize -> 46, 
        FontFamily -> "Lucida Handwriting"], FrameStyle -> None, 
       ImageMargins -> Scaled[.02]]], Background -> Purple]], 
   Polygon[Reverse @ {{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]};

object = {Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}]};

Graphics3D[{object, labels}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

**See also:** [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174899/125) for an alternative approach.

Comment: Thank you :) How do I alter the colour of the text, and the beige polygon underneath? Might sound simple but I can't get it to work

Comment: @Tom, you can use `Style["Some Label", Red]` instead of `"Some Label"` and `Background -> Purple`  (say) instead of `Background -> RGBColor[1., 0.92, 0.61]`.

Comment: Oh yes. Somehow it works here, but not for my similar answer below. Great thanks :)

Comment: Hmm. There's one last small problem with this answer. It has scaled the text to fill the entire box. But in the original label it was centered with some space around it

Comment: @Tom, please see the new version. You can control the spacing around framed text with the option `ImageMargins`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have managed a bodge job, that doesn't quite work, but gets half way there

```
label = {White, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, -1}, {0, -1}}]};
label = Graphics[{label, 
    Inset[Text["Some Label", 
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}], (1/2) {4, -1}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 0];
label = Image[label];
label3D = {Blue, Texture[label], 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 
       0}, {0, -1, 0}}]};
object = {Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}]};
Graphics3D[{object, label3D}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Result from above code]

It uses a trick. It makes an image from the 2D label, and then uses it as a `Texture` for a three-dimensional polygon. The problem is that I seem unable to control the colour of the resulting polygon. Note the random command `Blue` in the code that is just ignored.

Here's a slightly modified approach that uses `Opacity[0]` to achieve the effect I was ultimately after, which is a black text label with no colored box. Hopefully it is useful to someone.

```
label = {Opacity[0], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, -1}, {0, -1}}]};
label = Graphics[{label, 
    Inset[Text["Some Label", 
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 40}], (1/2) {4, -1}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 0];
label = Image[label];
label3D = {Texture[label], EdgeForm[White], 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, -1, 
       0}, {0, -1, 0}}]};
object = {Blue, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 3}]};
Graphics3D[{object, label3D}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Result from above code]