# Filling between two spheres in SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2 - n}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 1.5 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> {-2.2, 2.2}], {n, 0, 
  1}]
```

I cant' seem to be able to make a filling between two spheres. I've already tried the obvious `Filling -> {1 -> {2}}` but *Mathematica* doesn't seem to like that option.  Is there any easy way around this or ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14954/121 -- actually that one doesn't specifically relate to `SphericalPlot3D` and I can see that the solution may be a bit involved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built-in filling in `SphericalPlot3D`. One option is to use `ParametricPlot3D` to draw the surfaces between the two shells:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2 - n}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 1.5 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> {-2.2, 2.2}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{
    r {Sin[t] Cos[1.5 Pi], Sin[t] Sin[1.5 Pi], Cos[t]},
    r {Sin[t] Cos[0 Pi], Sin[t] Sin[0 Pi], Cos[t]}},
   {r, 1, 2 - n}, {t, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Yellow, Mesh -> {2, 15}]],
  {n, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a real bumer that there is no built in function, but thanks to kind and skillful people like you there is always a solution! :)

Answer (score 7):

Using RegionPlot3D is the easiest way to do it.

```
Manipulate[
Show[RegionPlot3D[1 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= (2 - n)^2 && (y >= 0 || x <= 0), {x, -2.2, 
2.2}, {y, -2.2, 2.2}, {z, -2.2, 2.2}, Mesh -> None, 
PlotPoints -> 50]], {n, 0, 1}];
```

[image]

You may want to render it before manipulating to avoid the recalculation, specially if you want better resolution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :)