# Plotting Semi-hollow spheres

Tags: graphics3d

I wish to create a nice data representation of three nested spherical sections, with a cut away so they can be viewed. As a MWE, something like;

```
a = SphericalPlot3D[{1}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 4 Pi/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]],
    Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40];

b = SphericalPlot3D[{2}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3 Pi/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}, PlotPoints -> 40];

c = SphericalPlot3D[{3}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3 Pi/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Green, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}, PlotPoints -> 40];

abc = Show[a, b, c, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

This gives me the following image, after some rotation for clarity;

[image: Nested spheres]

This is kind of the idea, but the problem is that this displays as spherical surfaces at r = 1, r = 2 and r = 3. In reality, there is a thick spherical shell (let's say a red one) for $1 \leq r \leq 2$ and a thick spherical shell (a green one) at $2 \leq r \leq 3$. The spherical core at $r \leq 1$ is solid blue. Is there a nice way to make this image? I was hoping I could somehow modify the $r$ term in the SphericalPlot3D function to do this.

I could also like to add a vertical line running through the sphere centre (z = 0) to make the image clearer. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why not try using Plot3D and Filling

Comment: Im not sure how to go about this, as AFAIR Plot3D only takes functions of 2 variables ? I suppose I could rewrite equation of sphere but seems messy..

Comment: Related: [(41985)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41985/filling-between-two-spheres-in-sphericalplot3d)

Comment: Related: [(14954)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14954)

Comment: http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/1/1.cover-expansion

Comment: In light of the post of @belisarius, I wonder if the answers here contributed significantly to your cover image? If so, attribution (which I don't see, but might have missed in the article) would be appropriate.

Comment: If you look below you'll see I thank Eldo for his suggestions, because I used some of his suggestions in the approach I took to fill in regions between the spheres. The data, the concepts and the rendering I had already put together, some (but not all) of which you see in the MWE. I do not think an attribution is appropriate, but thanks most certainly are!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SetOptions[{SphericalPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D}, Mesh -> None];

fun = {r {0, -Sin[t], Cos[t]}, r {Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}};

p1 = SphericalPlot3D[{2, 2.5},
   {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1.5 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p2 = ParametricPlot3D[fun,
   {r, 2, 2.5}, {t, 0, Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p3 = SphericalPlot3D[{1.5, 1.99},
   {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1.5 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p4 = ParametricPlot3D[fun,
   {r, 1.5, 1.99}, {t, 0, Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p5 = SphericalPlot3D[{1, 1.48},
   {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

**Edit**

With the new **V10** function `ClipPlanes` you can easily slice your graphics:

```
Grid[
 {{
   Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, ClipPlanes -> {{-1, 1, 0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 400],
   Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, -1, 0}}, ImageSize -> 400]
   }}]
```

[image]

Comment: @DRG Thanks for acceptance, interesting question :)

Comment: Nice use of ClipPlanes!

Comment: This image (or a derivation of it) has made the cover of the first volume of Royal Society Open Science: http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/1/1.cover-expansion

Comment: @blochwave Wow!, thank you!

Comment: Just spotted it!

Comment: Well spotted and cheers again - I used some of the techniques you kind folks outlined here to generate the image from my spheroid data, then just played with the light sources and orientation to make it look pretty as a supplementary addition to the paper!

Answer (score 7):

```
regionsandcolors =  Thread[
   {{(x <= 0 || y >= 0) && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1,
     (x <= 0 || y >= 0) &&  1 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 2,
     (x <= 0 || y >= 0) &&  2 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 3}, {Blue, Red, Green}}]; 
plots =  RegionPlot3D[#1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
       PlotStyle -> FaceForm[{Opacity[.9], #2}], 
       PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
       MaxRecursion -> 10] & @@@ regionsandcolors;
Show[plots]
```

[image]

Comment: This really had me puzzled.  So many simple ways that Mathematica ought to let one do this but doesn't ;-(  Great solution with broad application.  +1

Comment: @Jagra, thank you for the upvote. I agree, this seems to fall in the cracks between Mathematica's many `xPlot3D` functions:)

Comment: Very clever - I like this approach too. Thanks so much!